# javascript crop canvas to content

Tags: javascript, canvas, crop

How can I go about cropping a HTML canvas around only it's content?

I am using `strokeText` to fill the canvas so it is difficult to compute the size of the content. Can I iterate over every pixel of the canvas, or is there something better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *measureText* in advance to check how much space is taken by the text. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick, you can iterate through pixels in canvas, see "Pixel Manipulation" section in this awesome [cheatsheet](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas_sheet/HTML5_Canvas_Cheat_Sheet.png).

Of course, it is not an option - frankly, it would be just insane - to perform per-pixel analysis just to do something with text.
So here comes `measureText` mentioned by @RobotRock. It worth to mention, though, that, to my experience, measureText is not 100% reliable in some cases.

It is also worth to mention text manipulation properties from API: `textAlign` and `textBaseline`. Because there is >50% probability that if you asking about `measureText`, you actually want to align text somehow )))